# AJAX - Beep when new record is added to the database table

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can't figure out which condition to test for when a new record is added to the database table.
Can someone please help me out??

This is the database sample for the retrieved records

```
['Paul Abioro', 'paulexv...@gmail.com', 'chester', 'Teejay', 'Hi Teejay', '3', '2023-04-06 17:42:54']
['Paul Abioro', 'paulexv...@gmail.com', 'chester', 'Teejay', 'How are you doing?', '3', '2023-04-06 17:42:58']
```

This is the AJAX code to retrieve the records from the database, and I started a conditional statement, but do not know what to test "datum.length" against.

```
load_messages = function(){
     $.ajax({
         url:"json/chat-content.php",
         method:"POST",
         data:{recipient_id:query_id},
         dataType: "JSON",
         success:function(resp) {
          let datum = resp.response;
          //condition for when the new record is added to the database
           if(datum.length == ){
    
               let audio = new Audio("assets/audio/mixkit-confirmation-tone-2867.mp3");
               audio.play();

               

           }
            setTimeout(load_messages, 60000);
         },
         error: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
         }
     });

}
```

Comment: So store the last value and check if the length increases?

Comment: If this is something that you plan on keeping open, I would recommend maybe checking out websockets. They are made to do what you are trying to do via ajax.

Comment: @epascarello I know, but it's kinda tricky to execute as the last value (datum.length)  gets updated whenever AJAX runs

Comment: @imvain2 I would like to use AJAX at the moment.

Comment: Your server code should return both the old length and the new length, because it's at your server where the up-to-date information is located.

Comment: @devsam247 So you store the value after each call with the updated content. `if (lastLength > datum.length) { playSound() }; lastLength = datum.length`

Answer (score 1):

For my answer, I declare a variable **dataLength** with the initial value of 0. Then I use an if statement to check to see if that variable's value is less then your datum's length. Then after the if statement, I set **dataLength** to datum.length so it will be updated every time your ajax is completed.

```
let dataLength = 0;

load_messages = function(){
     $.ajax({
         url:"json/chat-content.php",
         method:"POST",
         data:{recipient_id:query_id},
         dataType: "JSON",
         success:function(resp) {
          let datum = resp.response;
          //condition for when the new record is added to the database
           if(dataLength < datum.length){
    
               let audio = new Audio("assets/audio/mixkit-confirmation-tone-2867.mp3");
               audio.play();
           }
            dataLength = datum.length;
            setTimeout(load_messages, 60000);
         },
         error: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
         }
     });

}
```